# How to close or destroy a class after calling it?

Tags: java, apex-code

I have a call to a method in a class as follows:

```
String key1 = "test1";
String key2 = "test2";

long[] datalr = new long[] {};

TestClass myTC1 = new TestClass(); 
datalr = myTC1.callerSub(key1,key2);
TestClass myTC2 = new TestClass(); 
datalr = myTC2.callerSub(key1,key2);
```

The test class is as follows:

```
public class TestClass {

  private final Long[] P = new Long[18];



  Public TestClass {
  }

  public long[] callerSub(string key1, String key2){

    long[] datalr = new long[] {0,0};
    integer i;
    system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,P[0]);

    datalr[0] = 2;
    datalr[1] = 3;
    for ( i = 0; i < 18; ++i ){
      P[i] = i+1
    }
    return datalr;

  }
}
```

I am calling the TestClass.callerSub twice,
The first time I call the debug statement:

```
system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,P[0]);
```

it returns null, as it should,

The second time I call it, the P[i] now has a value,

How do I close or destroy the TestClass class before I call it again?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your method is static?

You can make your P a variable, and not a static field anymore, or make your method an instance method and your field P an instance field (by removing the static keyword). Then you can create a new instance for each call: `new TestClass().callerSub(key1, key2)`

Answer (score 8):

You can't.  This is part of why static state is bad: `P` should not be static; it should be associated with an *instance* of `TestClass`.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to deleting an instance of a class you can do is removing all references to the class and calling system.gc() which *suggests* the jvm to run the garbage collector. There is no guarantee the jvm decides to run gc when you call it.

See Louis Wasserman's answer for an actual solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because P is a static field, it is created when the JVM starts up and is destroyed only on JVM shutdown.  In addition, because you made P a constant (using final), you cannot set P = null in order to suggest to the garbage collector that it should be deleted.  Thus, that array will be in the same location in memory and will always be pointed to by that static variable for as long as your program is running.